# There is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first - not because of MultipleActiveResultSets=false

Tags: c#, sql

Before people mark this as a duplicate: MultipleActiveResultSets is already set to be true in the app.config file, so that is not the cause :)

I am trying to use a method that should return a byte[] from the a row in the Users table of my database with a specific UserId and convert it to a List. Whenever I try to use this method I get the error stated in the title. I hope you can help :) Underneath is the method mentioned, the method for converting from byte[] to List and a few methods that are used along with this in the eventhandler that calls this method. Hope you guys can help :) Thanks in advance!

The method that causes the error (specifically the line inside the if(rdr.Read()) )

```
public List<int> GetHistory(string username, string password)
        {
            List<int> liste = new List<int>();

            cmd = new SqlCommand("select History from dbo.Users where Username = @uname and Password = @pword", conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", username);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pword", password);

            conn.Open();

            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (rdr.Read())
            {
                liste = ConvertFromByteArray(cmd.ExecuteScalar() as byte[]);
            }

            rdr.Close();
            conn.Close();


            return liste;
        }
```

The method for converting:

```
public List<int> ConvertFromByteArray(byte[] array)
{
    var mStream = new MemoryStream();
    var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    mStream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
    mStream.Position = 0;

    var liste = binFormatter.Deserialize(mStream) as List<int>;
    return liste;
}
```

The code for the eventhandler that I plan to use the method in:

```
private void btn_viewhistory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string uname = dbConnection.GetUsername(Convert.ToInt32(txt_id.Text));
    string pword = dbConnection.GetPassword(Convert.ToInt32(txt_id.Text));

    txt_history.Text =
        Convert.ToString(dbConnection.GetHistory(uname, pword)[0] + Environment.NewLine +
                         dbConnection.GetHistory(uname, pword)[1] + Environment.NewLine +
                         dbConnection.GetHistory(uname, pword)[2]);
}
```

The methods GetUsername and GetPassword that are also used in the eventhandler:

```
public string GetUsername(int id)
{
    string username = "";

    cmd = new SqlCommand("select Username from dbo.Users where UserId = @id", conn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

    conn.Open();

    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (rdr.Read())
    {
        username = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("Username"));
    }

    rdr.Close();
    conn.Close();

    return username;
}

public string GetPassword(int id)
{
    string password = "";

    cmd = new SqlCommand("select Password from dbo.Users where UserId = @id", conn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

    conn.Open();

    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (rdr.Read())
    {
        password = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("Password"));
    }

    rdr.Close();
    conn.Close();



    return password;
}
```

Comment: Your connection usage is all wrong. Your connections should be wrapped in using statements because they implement [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx). And do not store passwords in the database as plaintext! Passwords should be one way hashed and salted.

Comment: In your first snippet, you have `cmd.ExecuteReader()` followed a couple lines later with `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`. Seems wrong to me. If you have a reader, and you've called `Read()` on it, why are you calling `ExecuteScalar()`?

Comment: This code seems really janky. Also, why wouldn't you get the username and password in the same query? And finally, I do hope you're not storing plaintext passwords...

Comment: @DavidG I see a `conn.Open();` in every block.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @LarsTech Er, so it is. The rest of my comment stands though :)

Comment: I forgot to say that I am just learning to use sql and still learning C#, so this project is strictly for learning purposes - so no actual passwords are stored in my unsafe database :)

Comment: Nowhere in this code do you ever even define your `conn` object, or your `dbConnection` object.  It seems like a strange coincidence that *any* of this works *at all*.  You should really be creating/using/disposing your connections in a tight scope.  Trying to keep shared connections open is an open invitation to bugs and other problems (like the one you're experiencing).

Comment: But from what I can gather from your answers, I should be wrapping them in using() statements instead of doing it the way I do now, and I should not use ExecuteScalar()?

Comment: Why use the ExecuteScalar if you already have the reader open?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that.. My conn object is my connectionstring and the dbConnection is an instance of the class that stores all methods related to the database -  edit: sorry, not my connectionstring, my SQLConnection

Comment: Sounds like you should refactor your code really. Imagine you end up with 300 different types of database call, your single db class will be unmanageable!

Comment: There are *so* many examples of how to use the `SqlClient` namespace in C#. I recommend looking at those. There are so many problems with your current code, it's better to just start over.

Comment: Yea I guess that class got a bit out of hand - I'll look into that. And then change all the database methods to use the using() wrappers?

Comment: Haha, I guess I'll have to start over yeah - only way to learn it :)

Comment: A hint: do not store a `SqlConnection` as a field. They should be limited to the local block in scope. Which is simple if you create them in a using statement `using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) { /* your code that uses the connection here */ }`

Comment: @sunero4: For any given database query, you generally want to create/use/dispose your `SQLConnection` object in as small a space as possible.  Don't leave open connections, don't leave connection objects for other code to use, etc.  Creating a connection object is not a heavy operation, and the built-in connection pool does a lot of optimization for you.  You *can* use the same connection for more than one query, but at the very least as a general rule of thumb a `SqlConnection` object should not exceed the scope of a single method.

Comment: So basically I should create a new SqlConnection every time I want to use it in a method instead of storing it as a field in the class?

Comment: @sunero4: Pretty much, yes.  You certainly *can* store it in a higher scope, *if* you know what you're doing.  You're not there yet :)

Comment: Haha - thank you very much for your help guys :) Certainly learned a lot from this.